# How do I open a port on Linux Mint (VirtualBox guest) for the Redis Server?

Tags: linux, windows, port, redis

FWIW, I posted a related [programming question on Stack Overflow over here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56080984/961631).

I installed a Linux Mint on the VirtualBox to test a [Redis](https://redis.io/) Server I installed on.

The Linux machine is linked with the local network via a Bridged Adapter.

I installed the Redis Server on that Linux machine, but need to access it from a Windows (host) computer.

From the Linux Machine, the Redis Server is running on port number 6379, I need to expose it...

```
$ netstat -nlt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6379                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

From the Windows machine I do

```
C:\Users\myUser>nmap 10.14.30.51
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org )
Nmap scan report for 10.14.30.51
Host is up (0.00s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 10.14.30.51 are closed
MAC Address: 08:00:27:98:94:49 (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.56 seconds
```

but when I do the specific port it says:

```
C:\Users\my-user>nmap -p 6379 10.14.30.51
...
Nmap scan report for 10.14.30.51 Host is up (0.0010s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
6379/tcp filtered redis
MAC Address: 08:00:27:98:94:49 (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.80 seconds
```

Now

```
$ netstat -nlt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6379                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

The connection log I have

```
10.14.30.51:6379,abortConnect=False

Connecting 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive...
BeginConnect: 10.14.30.51:6379
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 10.14.30.51:6379 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=8190,Min=4,Max=8191)
Not all tasks completed cleanly (from ReconfigureAsync#1524, timeout 5000ms), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=8187,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 did not respond
Waiting for tiebreakers...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=8187,Min=4,Max=8191)
connection failed: 10.14.30.51:6379 (Subscription, UnableToConnect): UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Subscription, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
connection failed: 10.14.30.51:6379 (Interactive, UnableToConnect): UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=8188,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
No masters detected
10.14.30.51:6379: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
10.14.30.51:6379: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
resetting failing connections to retry...
retrying; attempts left: 2...
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 10.14.30.51:6379 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=8188,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 faulted: UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
Waiting for tiebreakers...
All tasks are already complete
10.14.30.51:6379 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
No masters detected
10.14.30.51:6379: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Disconnected; sub: Disconnected; not in use: DidNotRespond
10.14.30.51:6379: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
resetting failing connections to retry...
retrying; attempts left: 1...
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 10.14.30.51:6379 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
Not all tasks completed cleanly (from ReconfigureAsync#1524, timeout 5000ms), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=8187,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 did not respond
Waiting for tiebreakers...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=8186,Min=4,Max=8191)
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=8188,Min=4,Max=8191)
10.14.30.51:6379 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToConnect on 10.14.30.51:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 5s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402
No masters detected
10.14.30.51:6379: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Disconnected; sub: Disconnected; not in use: DidNotRespond
10.14.30.51:6379: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0,00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
Starting heartbeat...
```

My `redis.conf` file (only what is uncommented)

```
protected-mode yes
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
tcp-keepalive 300
supervised no
pidfile /var/run/redis_6379.pid
loglevel notice
logfile ""
databases 16
always-show-logo yes

save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes

rdbcompression yes

rdbchecksum yes

dbfilename dump.rdb
dir ./

################################# REPLICATION #################################
replica-serve-stale-data yes
replica-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
replica-priority 100

################################## SECURITY ###################################
requirepass redisdis

############################# LAZY FREEING ####################################
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
replica-lazy-flush no

############################## APPEND ONLY MODE ###############################
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes

################################ LUA SCRIPTING  ###############################
lua-time-limit 5000

################################## SLOW LOG ###################################
slowlog-max-len 128

################################ LATENCY MONITOR ##############################
latency-monitor-threshold 0

############################# EVENT NOTIFICATION ##############################
notify-keyspace-events ""

############################### ADVANCED CONFIG ###############################
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
stream-node-max-bytes 4096
stream-node-max-entries 100
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit replica 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
dynamic-hz yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
rdb-save-incremental-fsync yes
```

Comment: I searched "how to access redis server from VM to host" in Google and it shows may answers from StackExchange sites.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: Most of those answers don't apply because they are about "NAT"-mode virtual machines, where VirtualBox acts as a router with NAT. But in this case OP uses "bridged" mode, which attaches the VM directly to the same subnet as the host with no router or firewall in between.

Answer (score 0):

As the `Local Address` column notes, your Redis server is only **listening** for connections at the "localhost" addresses (that is, 127.0.0.1 and [::1]). You are however connecting to the address 10.14.30.51, which isn't listening for any connections.

This is just part of [Redis security model](https://redis.io/topics/security) – it isn't *designed* for use over a network and it doesn't require a password by default, instead it prioritizes network-level protection (listen address, firewall rules) such that other hosts couldn't connect to the service at all. (Because if they could, then all those wide-open Redis installations would become DDoS-generating machines, just as it has already happened with Memcached several times.)

To make Redis accessible over network, follow the previously linked article. The gist is:

1. Make sure the Linux system will *not* be reachable over the Internet, on the Redis port. Your home router probably provides a firewall that blocks incoming connections (and the server has a private IP address too), but that's not something that should be forgotten when configuring any server anyway.
2. Enable Redis password authentication using the `requirepass` redis.conf option.
3. Finally, remove redis.conf `bind` config options (such as `bind 127.0.0.1` or `bind ::1`) which tell it to restrict listening for connections to specific addresses only. After this, your netstat command should report that Redis is listening at the "all-zero" addresses 0.0.0.0 and [::].

Comment: actually I don't really care about the security, I just want my connection to be established... between my virtual box Linux and my host Windows computer ) I updated the OP scanning (from Windows) the exact 6379 port (the Linux one)

Comment: Did you also update redis.conf as described?

Comment: Did you also update redis.conf as described _in step 3_ too?

Comment: If you don't care about security, skip step 2 and just do step 3

Comment: updated the OP with the connection log and the new netstat

Comment: @grawity I added the redis.conf file content